Rails: problem with "@hotwired/turbo-rails" and redirects
// app/javascript/application.js
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
import "trix"
import "@rails/actiontext"
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
Rails.start()

# config/importmap.rb
# Pin npm packages by running ./bin/importmap

pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin "trix"
pin "@rails/actiontext", to: "actiontext.js"
pin "@rails/ujs", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@rails/ujs@7.0.4/lib/assets/compiled/rails-ujs.js"

For example in code I have:
= link_to 'Sing Out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, data:{turbo: false}

when I clicked Sing out i.e. new views coming from root_path are added. Turbo: false doesn't fix.
What I mean:
Before action
After Action
I can turn off turbo(like below) and then redirect work correctly:
// app/javascript/application.js
//import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
import "trix"
import "@rails/actiontext"
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
Rails.start()

I also tried something like below, but it didn't help:
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   
   ..................................................................

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    disable_turbo

    root_path
  end

  def disable_turbo
    response.set_header("Turbo-Frame", "_top")
  end
end

What is the problem with the turbo?

you should probably use rails ujs or turbo, not both. https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/main/UPGRADING.md#upgrading-from-rails-ujs--turbolinks-to-turbo

Try below one:
<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, data: { "turbo-method": :delete } %>

Hope it helps!

Nope. Your solution didn't solve the problem.
I had to change link_to to the form, something like:
 = form_with url: destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, local: true, data: { turbo: false} do
    = submit_tag 'Sign Out

And only then was the turbo turned off.
